# Using AWK to check a six column txt file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, scripting

I am brand new to using Awk and I am running into a bit of a problem. I have multiple tab delimited text files that are made up of six columns. The column layout is:

```
col1=int 

col2=float

col3=float

col4=int

col5=int

col6=DATE (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

The task at hand is to basically due a quality check on the text files to make sure that each column is that type. I also need to skip the first line since each tab delimited text file has has a header. So far this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk < file1.txt -F\\t '
{(NR!=1)}
{if ($1 != int($1)||($2 != /[0-9]+\.[0-9]*/)||($3 != /[0-9]+\.[0-9]*/)||($4 != int($4)||($5 != int($5))print "Error At " NR; }
'
```

I am not required to use Awk, it is just that it seemed the most appropriate.

EDIT 1:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk < file1.txt -F\\t '
{if (NR!=1){
  if ($1 != int($1)) print "Error col1 at " NR;
  else if ($4 != int($4)) print "Error col4 at " NR;
  else if ($5 != int($5)) print "Error col5 at " NR;
       }
}
'
```

This seems to work fine so my questions now are:

1- How do I check for floats?

2- How do I run this over multiple files?

Comment: It is not straight forward to test if a given string is float. Also, try to give some sample input and desired output, so we all work under the same settings

Comment: Get rid of the braces and parens around NR != 1. If you want, you can do a line "NR==1 {next}" to skip processing of the header line. From your regex, I assume your floats all have a decimal point, no sign or exponent...

Comment: Float could potentially be `x.y` or `x.` or `.y`. This also assumes the `.` character is used rather than `,` to separate the integral part from the fractional part and that no scientific notation is used. Please express which forms are valid.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Shouldn't be that difficult to match all those (minus the `,` as i don't think OP is using that notation). `'/-?([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?|\.[0-9])/'` would match `x.y` `.y` `x.` and the negative of each.

Comment: @123  if ($2 !=/-?([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?|\.[0-9])/) print "Error col2 at " NR;      is not working am i messing up the syntax?

Comment: `!=` is for literal strings, I'll let you look at the man page for how to match regex.

Comment: @123 !~   You are the man!

Comment: @123 I was referring to the complexity of the expression involved for performing a match; the number of accepted forms complicates the regexp, so if there was one specific notation accepted (e.g. only `x.y`), the regexp would be simpler.

Comment: @Don In your example you may want to use `int($1)~$1` to check for int as the  way you are currently doing it would not flag numbers like 1.0 as not an int. Not sure if that is a problem, just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: Is one thousand in your system represented by `1000` or `1,000` or can it be either or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't what you want then edit your question to include some sample input and expected output:

```
awk '
function act_type(n,    t) {
    if (n ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}$/) { t = "date"  }
    else if (n ~ /^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)  { t = "float" }
    else if (n ~ /^-?[0-9]+$/)          { t = "int"   }
    return t
}
BEGIN { split("int float float int int date",exp_type) }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (act_type(i) != exp_type[i]) {
            print "Error col", i, "at", NR. "in", FILENAME | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
}
' file
```

massage the regexp to suit your data (i.e. if your ints can start with `+` and/or include `,`s then include that in the regexp).

Answer (score 1):

To test if a field is a number, you can check if

```
$1 + 0 == $1
```

This works because adding to a string converts it to zero, if it isn't a number.

To run a script on multiple files, you can just add them as extra parameters, e.g.

```
awk 'commands' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: That test will succeed for any number. Just because `3 + 0 == 3` doesn't mean that `3` is a float.

Comment: @EdMorton That really depends on the use case. An integer is usually valid input when a float is expected. To test that it is a non integer number you could do `$1+0==$1 && $1!=int($1)`, but that would fail for 5.0. If the input is required to be a number containing a dot you need a regex.